# How to JOIN table with converting formate date on postgresql and Codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, join

I'am new on postgresql, i have some query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM "trx_mutualfund_trade" RIGHT JOIN "trx_mutualfund_nav" ON "trx_mutualfund_trade"."mtr_trade_time"::timestamp::date = trx_mutualfund_nav.mna_efective_date ....
```

and i try to write CI code like this :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mutualfund_trade');
$this->db->join('mutualfund_nav', 'mutualfund_trade.mtr_trade_time::timestamp::date = mutualfund_nav.mna_efective_date', 'right');
```

but that CI Code produces query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM "trx_mutualfund_trade" RIGHT JOIN "trx_mutualfund_nav" ON "trx_mutualfund_trade"."mtr_trade_time"::"timestamp::date" = mutualfund_nav.mna_efective_date...
```

So that can't run because there is an doublequote on `::"timestamp::date"`

Anyone can help me to show me how to write the CI code corectly?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM trx_mutualfund_trade RIGHT JOIN trx_mutualfund_nav ON trx_mutualfund_trade.mtr_trade_time::timestamp::date = trx_mutualfund_nav.mna_efective_date");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result
```